# Извлечение чисел перед специальным символом с помощью re

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть строка вида:

```
"123:345 876:788"
```

Как мне с помощью модуля `re` вытащить только те числа, которые стоят перед двоеточием? Такой вариант

```
re.findall(r'[0-9]+:', s)
```

возвращает такие числа только с доп двоеточием, которое мне не нужно. Полученный список конечно можно постобработать, но хотелось бы проделать все без лишних проходов или удалений.

Comment: ["This is called a lookahead assertion"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) `re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?=:)', '123:345 876:788')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При использовании `re.findall()` лучше использовать "захватывающую группу" (`capturing group`):

```
n [205]: re.findall(r"(\d+):", s)
Out[205]: ['123', '876']
```